# Get a list of classes in a namespace that are referenced by classes in other namespaces

Tags: .net, visual-studio

A have a Visual Studio solution, consisting of a number of C# projects. One of those projects contains a Service Reference. What I'd like to get is a list of classes defined by the Service Reference that are 'in use'. By 'in use' I mean classes that are being referenced by a classes other than a class within the Service Reference. The reverse would be useful too: A list of classes that aren't in use.

Any suggestions on how I can do this? If I were to do this manually I would for each class in the Service Reference, execute the `Find All References` command and copy the results to a spreadsheet, which I could then filter to get the information I need. Is there a way I can automate this somehow?

Comment: Have you looked at using Roslyn, if you're able to use VS2015?

Comment: I'll take a look - it's about time I upgrade to 2015 :) Just noticed that the final release is 3 days away!

Comment: You might want to wait until Monday, when it goes RTM :)

Comment: Would this be a good question for the Live Q&A on the release event, do you think? :)